# Migrate from Drupal to Standalone

Tags: standalone

I'm starting to test out Civi Standalone (something we've been waiting for, glad it's moving forward!) and I wanted to see how we might be able to migrate our data from a Drupal instance to the standalone instance.

I'm not sure if it's as simple as a mysqldump from the Drupal instance and loading to the standalone, as I believe standalone includes tables/data of the user accounts to log in.

Is there a way to migrate to a standalone instance? How do we migrate users? Also, where are the users in Standalone even stored (which db tables)?

Answer (score 2):

The Standalone extension repurposes the `civicrm_uf_match` table (which on CMS-based instances of CiviCRM stores a link to the CMS user record) to store username, password, etc. To stay consistent the tablename is still `civicrm_uf_match` but it get's labeled "Users".

Installing the standalone extension will delete and rebuild this table with the extra columns. If you have existing users to migrate you can then insert them into the table post-install. Every other table is the same, so migrating from another site should be as straightforward as a sql dump.

Comment: Thank you, @Coleman. Quick follow-up: does the Standalone version use the same password hashing method as Drupal? Can I simply copy the Drupal.users "pass" field into the hashed_password field of civicrm_uf_match?

Comment: I believe it is the same